# Replacing periods (".") in a string

Tags: python

I have a string of the type `../sometext/someothertext`, and I'm trying to replace the `..` in the string with the name of a website `http://www.website.com`.

In Python, what I've done is like so :

```
strName = "../sometext/someothertext"
strName.replace("..", "http://www.website.com")
print strName
```

But the only output I get is

```
../sometext/someothertext
```

I've also tried escaping the periods, like

```
strName = ../sometext/someothertext
strName.replace("\.\.", "http://www.website.com")
```

but the output doesn't change. How do I do this?

Comment: I am not a Python guy. But, if ../ always appears at the beginning, then I will just substring from 2 and append the website text at the beginning. I think this would be quicker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You didn't assign the result...

```
strName = strName.replace("..", "http://www.website.com")
```

`.replace` doesn't modify the original string but returns a new string with the modifications.

Comment: Indeed, this is not an in-place method.

Comment: Oh, crap... After reading the Python documentation, I thought this was an in-place substitution. Thanks! I feel like an idiot now. :P

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to specify a single replacement incase there are other .. in there

```
strName = strName.replace("..", "http://www.website.com", 1)
```